# How to display html file in Ionic 4

Tags: html, http, ionic-framework, request, ionic4

I send a request to the server. The server responses with html data, like below:

```
<html>
 <head> ...</head>
 <body>
  <form onsubmit="return onSubmit();">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
  <script> ....</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now how can I display the html data as a modal or Ionic page, that has a form with input tags and a submit button?

Answer (score 0):

put a div inside your ion-content for that modal, and then assign the html data to text property in your controller..

```
dummyHtml:any = `<div>your dummy html text here.</div>`;

    <ion-content>
       <div [innerHTML]="dummyHtml"></div> // this will populate your html inside this div.
    </ion-content>
```

Comment: Thnaks @Chestan, But the input and button is not showing.